# Secure Phonegap App and Asp.net WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am building the phonegap application and backend i am using Asp.net WebAPi REST,I want secure my Application and WEBApi,I want to know best practice for secure this,Kindly suggest me with any information or best tutroials or any blog which may help me.

Comment: Did you figure out how to approach this?